# Password value won't change when trying to login on a website

Tags: c#, html, httprequest, session-cookies, httpresponse

I'm trying to log in on a website and everything is fine but I noticed when I printed pageSource to the console **only** the nickname gets set, password value wont change... What is wrong with the code?

```
<form method="post">
    <input class="topbar_input" name="nickname" value="" 
    placeholder="Username" type="Text">
    &nbsp;
    <input class="topbar_input" name="passwort" value="" 
    placeholder="Passwort" type="Password">
    <input name="autologin" value="true" type="hidden">
    &nbsp;
    <button type="submit" name="checkid" value="Login">Login</button>
</form>
```

('passwort' is correct as its german)

This is my code:

```
String pageSource;
        String cookieHeader;

        //POST
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bytes = ascii.GetBytes(_credentials);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //GET PAGE AFTER LOGIN
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);

        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

The cookie looks something like this:

```
PHPSESSID=c4812cffcf2c45e0357a5a93c137642e; path=/
```

**EDIT:** Solved

Comment: try using `HttpClient` it will deal with storing the cookies for the lifetime of the usage :)

Comment: What's the issue - what would you expect here? Plaintext password?

Comment: well after I printed the pageSource at the end when I should be logged in, I noticed I wasn't. And thats why I think it has to be the password because nickname gets inserted correctly...